# is there a way to identify a query that has been cancelled?

Tags: sql-server, query-optimization, sql-server-2014, long-running-processes, dmv

I was running some big updates and while checking what else was running on that server, I saw an expensive query running, I then asked my friend who was running spid 91 if he could stop it, then he cancelled his query but there was no way I could see using any DMV that that was really the case.

what I could see is on the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

there is nothing there that tells me that this query has been cancelled.

is there any way, (preferably using DMVs or T-SQL) to find the processes that have been cancelled?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select session_id, Command
  From sys.dm_exec_requests
```

Look for **killed/rollback** or **rollback** in command.